# Erro 400 ao enviar requisição para o ESocial (C#)

Tags: c#, web-service, xml, soap, api

Estou recebendo como resposta o erro 400 ao executar a requisição SOAP nos servidores do eSocial. O erro ocorre nesse comando:

```
using (HttpWebResponse resposta = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
```

- Instalei as cadeias de certificados.
- Instalei as cadeias colocando todos os certificados no repositório Root da Local Machine
- Instalei as cadeias colocando somente o Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 no repositório Root e as demais no repositório das intermediárias.
- Instalei o Certificado (válido, não expirado e com senha correta) do meu cliente no repositório Pessoal (Na local Machine e no Usuário Atual).

Vale dizer que consigo acessar os endereços dos webservices pelo navegador e o cadeado fica verde.

Esse é o meu código:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Cria um webrequest SOAP para [Url]
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
private static string enviarRequisicao()
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        string web_service_teste =    "https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";                
        string xml_soap = @"C:\esocial\Templates\Esocial-S1000.xml";
        string url = web_service_teste;
        string response = "";
        Stream post = null;
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\esocial\certificado.pfx", "****");
        // build request objects to pass the data/xml to the server
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml_soap);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";                
        //request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

        using (post = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // post data and close connection
            post.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            post.Close();
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resposta = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var stream = resposta.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // Do something with result
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {                
        throw ex;                
    }
}
```

Esse é o XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v02_04_02">
            <envioLoteEventos grupo="1">
            <ideEmpregador>
                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                <nrInsc>78294442</nrInsc>
            </ideEmpregador>
            <ideTransmissor>
                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                <nrInsc>00254265000116</nrInsc>
            </ideTransmissor>
            <eventos>
                <evento Id="ID1333733250000002017122110411700002">
                    <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtTabRubrica/v02_04_02">
                        <evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1027327500001832016021911320900001">
                        <ideEvento>
                            <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                            <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                            <verProc>1.0</verProc>
                        </ideEvento>
                        <ideEmpregador>
                            <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                            <nrInsc>78294442</nrInsc>
                        </ideEmpregador>
                        <infoEmpregador>
                            <inclusao>
                                <idePeriodo>
                                    <iniValid>2017-10</iniValid>
                                </idePeriodo>
                                <infoCadastro>
                                    <nmRazao>LIGA ARTE MOVEIS LTDA EPP</nmRazao>
                                    <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                                    <natJurid>399-</natJurid>
                                    <indCoop>0</indCoop>
                                    <indConstr>0</indConstr>
                                    <indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha>
                                    <indOptRegEletron>1</indOptRegEletron>
                                    <indEntEd>N</indEntEd>
                                    <indEtt>N</indEtt>
                                    <contato>
                                    <nmCtt>Cristiano dos Santos Lagame</nmCtt>
                                    <cpfCtt>09673071713</cpfCtt>
                                    <foneFixo>2122740494</foneFixo>
                                    </contato>
                                    <softwareHouse>
                                    <cnpjSoftHouse>00254265000116</cnpjSoftHouse>
                                    <nmRazao>LIGA ARTE MOVEIS LTDA EPP</nmRazao>
                                    <nmCont>Cristiano dos Santos Lagame</nmCont>
                                    <telefone>21993623199</telefone>
                                    <email>cristiano@madeirol.com.br</email>
                                    </softwareHouse>
                                    <infoComplementares>
                                    <situacaoPJ>
                                        <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                                    </situacaoPJ>
                                    <situacaoPF>
                                        <indSitPF>0</indSitPF>
                                    </situacaoPF>
                                    </infoComplementares>
                                </infoCadastro>
                            </inclusao>
                        </infoEmpregador>
                        </evtInfoEmpregador>
                        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <SignedInfo>
                            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                            <Reference URI="">
                                <Transforms>
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                </Transforms>
                                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                            </Reference>
                        </SignedInfo>
                        <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                        <KeyInfo>
                            <X509Data>
                                <X509Certificate>TqIsONfPFt6L9tVM3CElBZeynQ1AlzzyZhpNX9YUTgiALPhv4eCxF/I0djghAj56FYBJMeWA4uwyGLA9L6VWMO1ksnuAsBHTWNd4/CI2IflwhlbCujgP91rBZOZJnr0YCQM9El92dUhVB0zBkFLvP14lDbyRIivF76ZlG3EeCCp8eCPi2QFoVY8N9tUpBNDSJPqkXSxgxvxPXQqfRsmwqoeVvd8sFKEmO4a5crmPbyExYOrrjoQoFhhgiagmS3O8rtjXBsWV9pKx435/mOMmU3/hGrWlIJfx4FQ7loqQZh/NVHRTXguMqua2m3QzSkVfw5oreZxbGUh9i0uZ0Dpocg==</X509Certificate>
                            </X509Data>
                        </KeyInfo>
                        </Signature>
                    </eSocial>
                </evento>
            </eventos>
            </envioLoteEventos>
        </eSocial>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Detalhe, cheguei a ter o erro 403, mas resolvi através [deste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307442/como-referenciar-os-webservices-do-esocial-pelo-visual-studio).

---

**Atualização:** O XML estava incorreto, [descobri aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281314/o-documento-enviado-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-um-xml-valido-do-esocial) qual era a formatação correta. Eu achei importante mencionar aqui que mudei o código para este abaixo com as instruções do @Pedro Gaspar:

```cs
private static string enviarRequisicao()
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        //string web_service_teste = "https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
        //              string web_service_producao = "https://webservices.envio.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";

        string urlXML = @"C:\esocial\Templates\Esocial-S1000.xml";

        X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\esocial\certificado.pfx", "12345678");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        XDocument loteEventosXDoc = XDocument.Load(urlXML);

        var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
        var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
        var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();  //Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5
                                                // ou:
                                                //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 768000;

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var wsClient = new PortalMadeirol.Web.ServiceEsocial.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient(binding, address);
        
        // Variável 'x509Cert' é do tipo X509Certificate2.

        wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

        var retornoEnvioXElement = wsClient.EnviarLoteEventos(loteEventosXDoc.Root);
        wsClient.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: O erro 400 geralmente está relacionado ao conteúdo que você está enviando, onde o servidor não está conseguindo validar como uma requisição válida.

Comment: Tentou enviar sem o wrapper do post? apenas o `<eSocial>`?

Comment: Olá @LeandroAngelo, tentei sim. Também acredito que este seja o problema, então eu teria que encontrar algum exemplo de XML que funcione, certo?

Comment: @CristianoLagame, mas, por que motivo você está tentando fazer o trêmite do SOAP "na mão", usando `HttpWeRequest` ao invés de deixar o .NET fazer o serviço para você? Por que você não cria uma referência ao serviço no Visual Studio e usa a classe criada, que herda a `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`? Nessa pergunta mesmo que você linkou tem um link para um exemplo de código que eu escrevi: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277465/86952, e tem vários exemplos em várias outras perguntas aqui no SO, mas são todos similares.

Comment: De qualquer forma, segundo alguns exemplos que eu vi, faltou você informar o SOAP Action no header do request, como `webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action)`. Mas os exemplos que eu vi estavam acessando aquele serviços antigos do tipo ASP.NET Web Service (ASMX), não sei se o mesmo código funcionaria para serviços mais modernos, lembrando que o acesso ao serviço do eSocial usa o protocolo de segurança TLS.

Comment: @CristianoLagame, veja esse link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/ssl-httpwebrequest-in-c-sharp-could-not-create-ssltls-secure-channel, lembrando que o protocolo de segurança que o eSocial usa é o TLS, ele aceita as versões 1.0, 1.1 e 1.2, embora em alguns computadores você pode ter problemas se usar algo diferente do TLS 1.0, veja essa minha pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318351/86952

Comment: Pedro, de onde vem a variável x509Cert que você menciona no outro post? E não estou sabendo também como loteEventosXDoc.Root é preenchido, dá erro aqui pra mim "Error CS0103: The name 'loteEventosXDoc' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Cristiano, o certificado você pode carregar do mesmo jeito que você está fazendo, o resultado já é um objeto do tipo `X509Certificate2`, que é o esperado, e a variável `loteEventosXDoc` você pode fazer assim: `XDocument loteEventosXDoc = XDocument.Load(xml_soap);` (para usar o tipo **XDocument** você precisa fazer referência à biblioteca `System.Xml.Linq`).

Comment: Mas aí, claro, esqueci de comentar, você precisasria alterar o seu arquivo XML de teste, ele não poderia mais conter o envelope SOAP, somente o lote do eSocial mesmo, porque aí o .NET passaria a criar o envelope SOAP e cuida de tudo isso para você.

Comment: Tranquilo, eu removi, e desde já agradeço sua atenção até aqui.

Agora está dando um erro antes de compilar, na linha 
    var wsClient = new WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient(binding, address);
O erro é esse: The type ou namespace name 'WsEnviar' could not be found...

Comment: O meu código está assim porque eu chamei o serviço de `WsEnviar` quando adicionei a referência do serviço ao projeto, mas se você usou um nome diferente, tem que usar aí o mesmo nome que você usou ao adiciona-lo.

Comment: Funcionou! Retornou o XML e lá tava a tão sonhada mensagem: Lote Recebido com Sucesso.

Comment: Só ficou faltando acertar o XML, recebi um aviso de "Lote Incorreto - Schema Inválido", mas já corrigi através do link abaixo eu achei a formatação correta do XML.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281314/o-documento-enviado-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-um-xml-valido-do-esocial

Comment: Que bom Cristiano. Se puder dá um voto positivo então lá nas respostas que te ajudaram! Assim você melhora a visibilidade das respostas, porque está indicando que elas foram úteis, e também ajuda o autor da resposta a ganhar uns pontos e melhorar a reputação no Stack Overfow PT.  ;-)

Comment: Só aparece a opção de sinalizar como impróprio, não tá aparecendo em nenhuma das respostas a opção de aceitar como resposta...
Inclusive já li esse link pra ver onde deveria aparecer a marca de verificação e não encontrei: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Você só pode marcar como resposta quando foi você quem fez a pergunta, mas você pode clicar na setinha pra cima para votar na resposta como útil (no lado esquerdo superior de cada resposta, e também das perguntas). Você já fez o tour do site? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Já fiz o tour, e fui em quem fez a pergunta... Estranho, não aparecem as setinhas...

Comment: Então Cristiano, você fez **esta** pergunta, mas esta pergunta não teve uma resposta! Eu estava me referindo às respostas das outras perguntas, dos links que você postou, que te ajudaram a resolver o problema: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307466/86952, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285167/86952 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277465/86952.

Comment: Ainda não tenho 15 pontos de reputação... Então não consigo votar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cristiano, apesar de ter sugerido nos comentários que você criasse uma referência ao serviço do eSocial, através do WSDL do serviço, e usasse a classe gerada que herda `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`, para que o .NET faça todo o trabalho de comunicação SOAP para você, ao invés de você ter que fazer tudo na mão (sugestão inclusive que você aceitou e já fez funcionar), por curiosidade, e para tentar responder sua pergunta original, tentei fazer fazer funcionar o seu código original, acessando o eSocial "na mão" através do `HttpWebRequest`.

Eu tive que fazer algumas correções no XML, como você já tinha comentado, em alguns namespaces, mas também tive que incluir o grupo `EnviarLoteEventos` no início do corpo da mensagem, então o XML ficou assim (também troquei seus dados pessoais):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <EnviarLoteEventos xmlnm="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
         <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
            <envioLoteEventos grupo="1">
               <ideEmpregador>
                  <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                  <nrInsc>87654321</nrInsc>
               </ideEmpregador>
               <ideTransmissor>
                  <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                  <nrInsc>12345678901234</nrInsc>
               </ideTransmissor>
               <eventos>
                  <evento Id="ID1876543210000002017122110411700002">
                     <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_04_02">
                        <evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1876543210001832016021911320900001">
                           <ideEvento>
                              <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                              <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                              <verProc>1.0</verProc>
                           </ideEvento>
                           <ideEmpregador>
                              <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                              <nrInsc>78294442</nrInsc>
                           </ideEmpregador>
                           <infoEmpregador>
                              <inclusao>
                                 <idePeriodo>
                                    <iniValid>2017-01</iniValid>
                                 </idePeriodo>
                                 <infoCadastro>
                                    <nmRazao>RAZÃO EMPREGADOR</nmRazao>
                                    <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                                    <natJurid>2062</natJurid>
                                    <indCoop>0</indCoop>
                                    <indConstr>0</indConstr>
                                    <indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha>
                                    <indOptRegEletron>1</indOptRegEletron>
                                    <indEntEd>N</indEntEd>
                                    <indEtt>N</indEtt>
                                    <contato>
                                       <nmCtt>Nome Contato</nmCtt>
                                       <cpfCtt>12345678901</cpfCtt>
                                       <foneFixo>2112345678</foneFixo>
                                    </contato>
                                    <softwareHouse>
                                       <cnpjSoftHouse>12345678901234</cnpjSoftHouse>
                                       <nmRazao>RAZÃO SOFTWAREHOUSE</nmRazao>
                                       <nmCont>Nome Contato</nmCont>
                                       <telefone>21123456789</telefone>
                                       <email>nomeusuario@dominio.com.br</email>
                                    </softwareHouse>
                                    <infoComplementares>
                                       <situacaoPJ>
                                          <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                                       </situacaoPJ>
                                    </infoComplementares>
                                 </infoCadastro>
                              </inclusao>
                           </infoEmpregador>
                        </evtInfoEmpregador>
                        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                           <SignedInfo>
                              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                              <Reference URI="">
                                 <Transforms>
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                 </Transforms>
                                 <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                 <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                              </Reference>
                           </SignedInfo>
                           <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                           <KeyInfo>
                              <X509Data>
                                 <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
                              </X509Data>
                           </KeyInfo>
                        </Signature>
                     </eSocial>
                  </evento>
               </eventos>
            </envioLoteEventos>
         </eSocial>
      </EnviarLoteEventos>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

No código eu alterei a forma de ler o XML:

```
//byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml_soap);
XDocument soapEnvelopeXml = XDocument.Load(xml_soap);

//[...]

   //post.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   soapEnvelopeXml.Save(post);
```

E aí o erro passou de **400** (*"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."*) para **500** (*"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."*).

Graças a essa resposta aqui, do SO<sup>EN</sup>: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21881566/8133067, eu melhorei o tratamento de erro para saber exatamente qual o erro que estava acontecendo, foi aí que arrumei o XML.

Também foi essencial informar o `SOAPAction` no cabeçalho da requisição, porque é isso que indica qual método do serviço deve ser chamado.

Então, o seu código alterado ficou assim:

```
private static string enviarRequisicao()
{
   try
   {
      string web_service_teste = "https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
      string xml_soap = @"C:\esocial\Templates\Esocial-S1000.xml";
      string url = web_service_teste;
      X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\esocial\certificado.pfx", "****");

      //byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml_soap);
      XDocument soapEnvelopeXml = XDocument.Load(xml_soap);

      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

      request.Method = "POST";
      request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_0/ServicoEnviarLoteEventos/EnviarLoteEventos");
      request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
      //request.Accept = "text/xml";
      //request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
      request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

      using (Stream post = request.GetRequestStream())
      {
         // post data and close connection
         //post.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         soapEnvelopeXml.Save(post);
         //post.Close();
      }

      using (HttpWebResponse resposta = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
      {
         using (var stream = resposta.GetResponseStream())
         {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
               var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
               return result;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   catch (WebException webex)
   {
      WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
      using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
      {
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
         string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
         return text;
      }
   }
}
```

O SOAPAction eu descobri olhando o WSDL do serviço, em:

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

Dessa forma para mim funcionou.

Comment: Pedro, já te disse hoje que você é o cara?! Perfeito!

Comment: Obrigado Cristiano, hehe... Se puder, depois dá um voto positivo lá nas outras respostas que te ajudaram, agora que você já tem reputação suficiente, para ajudar a dar mais visibilidade para as repostas!